# How to pass state value from child to parent from a mapped select/option

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to pass the "year" value back from a child component to the parent component. I am able to get the value passed back however after my props/function runs in the child component it resets the selection option to the default "choose a year" (but correctly passes the chosen year back to the parent component).

I am not sure if it is due to me mapping through the array and the function refreshing the component after each change?

```
function MapComponent() {

  const [input1, setInput1] = useState("");

  const setVehicleInfoInput = (value) => {
    setInput1(value)
  }

return (
    {input1} // shows the selected year from child component
    <VehicleInput setVehicleInfoInput={setVehicleInfoInput} sendYear={input1} />
)

export default React.memo(MapComponent)


const VehicleInput = ({setVehicleInfoInput, sendYear}) => {

  let vehicleYearsArray = ["2000","2001","2002","2003" etc ]

  let handleYearSelection = (e) => {
    setVehicleInfoInput(e.target.value)
  }

  return (

// sends the chosen year to parent component but then resets to "choose a year" rather than also showing the chosen year in the dropdown/select

   <select value={sendYear} className='vehicleInput' onChange={handleYearSelection}>
     <option value="Choose a Year"> -- Choose a Year -- </option>
     {vehicleYearsArray.map((year) => (
     <option value={year}>{year}</option>
     ))}
   </select>

)

export default VehicleInput;
```

Thank you for any assistance

Comment: Your `<select>` needs a `value`

Comment: I would need to dynamically update that value with a state in the child component then?

Comment: No, pass it down from the parent

Comment: @CertainPerformance please see my latest edit. I passed Input1 to the child component but it does not seem to carry the state with it. If I print {sendYear} in the child component it is empty. If i send Input1 = "some string" in the parent component it will show "some string" in the child component. But I cannot get it to pass the updated state with the year.

Comment: You have a typo, `value="sendYear"` is the literal string `"sendYear"`

Comment: sorry that was a typo in my snippet but it is written properly in my ide.

Comment: using useImperativeHandle(ref, createHandle, dependencies?) you can use your child component  all property in parent component